# The application is not compatible with any device in the Google Play Console, but is compatible on the developer console

Tags: android, google-play, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-webview, android-manifest

My application has been published but in the Play Store, but on the Play Store it says my application is not compatible with all my devices, Xiaomi Redmi, Xiaomi Poco, and Samsung Note. After searching in the internet, I found a solution, by add the code `android:required=false` in `<uses-feature>` in the manifest file, for all features, after I added the code, the play store still said my application was not compatible with all my devices.
this is my manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.com">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.capability.manual_post_processing" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.capability.manual_sensor" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.external" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.full" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.manual_post_processing" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.manual_sensor" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false" />
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/newlogo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logoround"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                    />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
                    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                    />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".FcmMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

can anyone help for this?

Answer (score 0):

Update!!! After I change it from a paid application to a free application, Play Store says my device is compatible, thank you.